# Changing tensor value from a saved tensorflow model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, dropout

I have some models saved that have dropout layers. Unfortunately, the **dropout_keep_dim** value was not given as placeholders. Now when I restore the model for test purpose, it gives random output for each run. So, my question is, is it possible to change the **dropout_keep_dim** of a saved variable? The dropout layer is added the following way:

```
tf.nn.dropout(layer_no, dropout_keep_dim)
```

I have already wasted hours on google and didn't find any working solution. Is there even a solution or are my saved models of no use now? Tf.assign doesn't work as, in my case, dropout_keep_dim is not a variable. Any kind of help is appreciated.

NB. I can restore the **dropout_keep_dim** value and print it. I want to change it if that's possible and then test with the saved weights.

Comment: Do you have the code that builds the graph?

Comment: Yes, I have the code. It's a simple 3 layer NN.

Comment: Then I don't understand what the problem is...Maybe add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so people understand where you're stuck...

Comment: Suppose I have a saved model. Now I'm restoring it, and I want to change its dropout value. How can I do this without retraining? I want to use the saved models.

Comment: I understood that much, I don't understand _where_ things are going wrong. Did you read about MCVEs? just show your code and what you tried that didn't work. I'd like to help, but there isn't much do base myself on here...